# In Typescript, how can I declare an object as a mix of an interface and its declared values?

Tags: typescript, types

In Typescript if I declare the following constant:

```js
const myConstant {
  baseAttributes: {
    a: '123',
    b: '234'
  },
  extraAttributes: {
    c: 'abc',
    d: 'def'
  },
}
```

Typescript considers this constant as the definition of its own type. I can write

myConstant.baseAttributes.

and expect autocompletion, as the type checker knows all the properties contained in the constant.

However, let's suppose I want to impart these objects a fixed structure: I want to be able to declare constants that have each a dictionary under baseAttributes and extraAttributes.

```js
interface IConstant {
  baseAttributes: any,
  extraAttributes: any,
}
```

Now, if I write:

```js
const myConstant: IConstant {
  baseAttributes: {
    a: '123',
    b: '234'
  },
  extraAttributes: {
    c: 'abc',
    d: 'def'
  },
}
```

I lose type checking on the actual content of baseAttributes and extraAttributes, as they are explicitly declared as 'any'.
Is there a practical way to both enforce the structure given by the interface and narrow it down to the properties actually defined in the constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure to understand the purpose of your code, but anyway let me try to help on what I could get:

- Let's say you already have this type defined

  ```js
  interface IConstant {
      baseAttributes: any,
      extraAttributes: any,
  }
  ```
- To avoid issues with the "any" type I would recommend you to enhance the typings in this way:

  ```js
   interface AnyObject<T = any> {
       [key:string]: T;
   }

   interface IConstant {
       baseAttributes: AnyObject<string>,
       extraAttributes: AnyObject<string>,
   }
  ```

In this way, you get better typings definition and more flexible to have any kind of properties inside of `baseAttributes` and `extraAttributes`.

- As another possible solution to your problem, you could merge the types to keep the code completion based on an existing inferred type:

  ```js
  // if you want to restrict the initial type you can declare them as "unknown"
  interface IConstant {
      baseAttributes: unknown,
      extraAttributes: unknown,
  }

  // using this constant to infer the typings
  const myConstant = {
      baseAttributes: {
          a: '123',
          b: '234'
      },
      extraAttributes: {
          c: 'abc',
          d: 'def'
      }
  };

  // merge the inferred type from "myConstant" with your previous interface
  type CusomIConstant = IConstant & typeof myConstant;

  // now you can use the custom type with code completion
  const sample: CustomIConstant = {...};
  ```

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to get type checking on the structure of the constant (it has to conform to a certain structure) *and* to get type checking when I'm using it, down to its actual keys. Your second suggestion seems logically correct (if a bit impractical), but I've tried it and strangely it doesn't seem to work. If I export 

const myConstant: IConstant & typeof tmpConstant = tmpConstant;

I still don't get code checking/ completion.

Comment: If you go for the 2nd solution you should keep it strict to the inferred type. For me was working perfectly and for that case I didn't use the `AnyObject` type from the 1st solution as it would make the type flexible to any key. Give it a try and let me know

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you correctly. Here's a demo with what I understand from your idea: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-de5ds9

Comment: @udik I checked your demo and added some code & comments which should solve your problems, check it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nvcuv4?file=index.ts

Comment: thanks! Indeed defining the interface properties type as 'unknown' did the trick! If you update your answer I'll accept it, it might be useful to others.

Comment: @udik I updated the answer, happy to hear that it suit you well. Remember to define the type while defining the variables, that also helps on a better type hinting

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use generic?

```js
interface IConstant<T, U> {
  baseAttributes: T,
  extraAttributes: U,
}
```

and you can use a function to infer the types

```js
const makeConstant = <T, U> (constant: IConstant<T, U>) => constant

const myConstant = makeConstant({
  baseAttributes: {
    a: '123',
    b: '234'
  },
  extraAttributes: {
    c: 'abc',
    d: 'def'
  },
})
```

Or leave the type checking when you actually need to use the object.

```js
const useConstant = (constant: IConstant<*, *>) => {
  console.log(constant); // do stuff
}
```

```js
const myConstant = {
  baseAttributes: {
    a: '123',
    b: '234'
  },
  extraAttributes: {
    c: 'abc',
    d: 'def'
  },
}

useConstant(myConstant); // no error
```

```js
const notMyConstant = {
  baseAttributes: {
    a: '123',
    b: '234'
  },
  blab: {
    c: 'abc',
    d: 'def'
  },
}

useConstant(notMyConstant); // error
```